# limit size JLD2 Julia

Tags: julia

Is there a size limit to load data using JLD2 in Julia?

The same code:

```
using JLD2
using FileIO
exp=load("myfile.jld2");
```

seems to work fine until a certain size of data. For some experiments I ran, the file is 5GB and I obtain the following :

> Error encountered while loading "/pathtofile/myfile.jld2".
>   Fatal error:
>
> ERROR: EOFError: read end of file
>
> Stacktrace:
>
> [1] handle_error(::EOFError, ::File{DataFormat{:JLD2}}) at /path/.julia/packages/FileIO/Y0Lre/src/error_handling.jl:80
>
> [2] handle_exceptions(::Array{Any,1}, ::String) at /path/.julia/packages/FileIO/Y0Lre/src/error_handling.jl:75
>
> [3] #load#27(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::File{DataFormat{:JLD2}}) at /path/.julia/packages/FileIO/Y0Lre/src/loadsave.jl:193
>
> [4] load(::File{DataFormat{:JLD2}}) at /path/.julia/packages/FileIO/Y0Lre/src/loadsave.jl:172
>
> [5] #load#13(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::String) at /path/.julia/packages/FileIO/Y0Lre/src/loadsave.jl:118
>
> [6] load(::String) at /path/.julia/packages/FileIO/Y0Lre/src/loadsave.jl:118
>
> [7] top-level scope at none:0

I tried using jldopen which I have no experience in using at all but I also get similar error messages.

What could I do ?

And, btw, what is the difference between load and jldopen("my file.jld2","r")?

I am using Julia Version 1.0.2 on Mac OSHighSierra 10.13.6.

Comment: Note that there are good (and sometimes more stable) alternatives to JLD2. For short term serialization have a look at the standard library https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.0/stdlib/Serialization/ and for long term serialization https://github.com/MikeInnes/BSON.jl might be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks! Very useful

Comment: Glad to help. Note that on Stackoverflow you click the "up" arrow when you find answers of other people useful rather than writing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I regularily read >5GB files without problems. So I assume that, for some reason, your file wasn't written correctly. This is also indicated by the error message.

To answer your other question, the differene between `load("myfile.jld2")` and `jldopen("myfile.jld2", "r")` is that the former loads all the contents of the file into a dictionary whereas the latter opens the file and returns a `JLDFile` object which you can use to get fine grained access to your data file. For example it allows you to write multiple datafields to the same file (Note that multiple `save` commands overwrite the same file).

**Demonstration**:

```
julia> using FileIO, JLD2

julia> jldopen("myfile.jld2", "w") do f
           write(f, "x", rand(10))
           write(f, "y", "test")
       end

julia> load("myfile.jld2")
Dict{String,Any} with 2 entries:
  "x" => [0.918336, 0.608631, 0.757459, 0.935133, 0.548579, 0.909, 0.913573, 0.0278975, 0.…

  "y" => "test"

julia> load("myfile.jld2", "y")
"test"

julia> f = jldopen("myfile.jld2", "r")
JLDFile C:\Users\carsten\myfile.jld2 (read-only)
 ├─� x
 └─� y

julia> typeof(f)
JLD2.JLDFile{JLD2.MmapIO}

julia> f["x"]
10-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.9183355611466055
 0.6086314948624771
 0.757458522055442
 0.9351333595616453
 0.5485794420648191
 0.9089998574850378
 0.9135729509843764
 0.027897482037234633
 0.5827560900500541
 0.9831034815173016

julia> close(f)
```